# How can you write raw JSON through Jackson's JsonGenerator?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to generate a JSON String in the following structure using Jackson API (JsonFactory,JsonGenerator). How can i do it ?

Expected:

```
{
    "api": {
        "Salutaion": "Mr",
        "name": "X"
    },
    "additional": {
        "Hello",
        "World"
    }
}
```

Actual:

```
{
    "api": "{
        \"Salutaion\": \"Mr\",
        \"name\": \"X\"
    }",
    "additional": "{
        \"Hello\",
        \"World\"
    }"
}
```

The values of the attributes api & additional will be available to me as String. Should i be using writeObjectField (as follows) ?

```
jGenerator.writeObjectField("api", apiString);
```

***After constructing the jGenerator object, how do i get the final constructed JSON Object's String representation ?***

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(outputStream);
           jGenerator.writeStartObject();

           jGenerator.writeObjectField("api", apiString);
           jGenerator.writeObjectField("additional", additionalString);

           jGenerator.writeEndObject();                    

           jGenerator.close();        
           outputStream.close();
           outputStream.toString()
```

The outputStream.toString() gives a json string but the double quotes (") in the apiString are getting prefixed with an escape character \

Is this the right way ?

Comment: yes it is right, unless it is invalid

Comment: actually, the apiString is a JSON String. Should i be using writeTree() to ensure i get the final string as depicted in the question ?

Comment: I don't understand. What is `apiString`? Is it a `String` that contains JSON content?

Comment: yes , {"Salutaion": "Mr","name": "X"}  is the value of apiString String variable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming `apiString` and `additionalString` are references to `String` objects with JSON content, you'll want to write them raw, ie. their content directly. Otherwise, you're serializing them as JSON strings and Jackson will need to escape any relevant characters.

For example

```
jGenerator.writeFieldName("api");
jGenerator.writeRawValue(apiString);
```

for `api`, and the same for `additional`.